# flutter test fails. compiler error getter not found 'main'

Tags: testing, dart, flutter, mockito, bloc

I'm trying to run flutter test using the terminal and i receive the following error. the following file C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/flutter_test_listener.e6fa92b4-6cd1-11e9-b9cb-68f728ca4610/listener.dart 
doesn't exist in the directory specified.

here's the error:

> Compiler message:
>       file:///C:/Users/User-45/AppData/Local/Temp/flutter_test_listener.e6fa92b4-6cd1-11e9-b9cb-68f728ca4610/listener.dart:46:17:
>
> Error:Getter not found: 'main'.  return test.main;

my project's directory is in another folder. how can i solve this? Thank you

Answer (score 14):

In my case, it happened that one of my helper classes in the test folder, had a name that ended "_test", and the compiler was looking for a main method. So I renamed the helper class, and problem solved.

Comment: I had to execute flutter clean after I renamed the helper classes and then it works fine :)

Comment: OMG it really saved me... I was clueless on this error

Answer (score 6):

If anybody faces the above problem then try to add `main()` in test class and if you have added then remove it out of test class curly braces. I faced this and removed the `main()` out of test class.

Eg...

```
class GetConcreteNumberTrivia_Test extends Mock
    implements NumberTriviaRepository {}

void main() {

.....my implementation......
}
```

Comment: You made my day. I was testing the same code from `resocoder` like yours, and this solution fixed it

Answer (score 6):

It seems this error can have a lot of different causes. In my case the problem was a file `foo_test.dart` with the only content `//TODO`. So it was basically empty and the compiler could not find the excpected main method. The weird thing was, that it threw the Error in another test!

When I removed `foo_test.dart`, it worked again! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I had this error when a merge mess put the main() within a class.

Comment: I didn't have a merge mess, I just came from java and put the main method in a test class because I didn't know any better. This is likely the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

I also got this error. My problem has been how I named the files for my tests. The test runner is looking for this pattern "*_test.dart" ([hier](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Running-and-writing-tests)). After renaming my test files accordingly, the test runner executes the test without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had kept my expect() condition outside of the test method

```
test('',(){
    // expect()/assertion should be here
})
//not here
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for the latest dependencies (01/16/2022). Complete answer for 2-3 errors:

added:   `build_runner: ^2.1.7` to pubspec.yaml

```
//...
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';

class MockNumberTriviaRepository extends Mock implements NumberTriviaRepo {}

@GenerateMocks([NumberTriviaRepo])
void main() {
  late GetConcreteNumberTrivia usecases;
  late MockNumberTriviaRepository mockNumberTriviaRepository;
  late int tNumber;
  late NumberTrivia tNumberTrivia;
  setUp(() {
    mockNumberTriviaRepository = MockNumberTriviaRepository();
    usecases = GetConcreteNumberTrivia(repo: mockNumberTriviaRepository);
    tNumber = 1;
    tNumberTrivia = NumberTrivia(text: 'test', number: 1);
  });

  test('should get a trivia for the number from the repo', () async {
    // arrange
    when(mockNumberTriviaRepository.getConcreteNumberTrivia(tNumber))
        .thenAnswer((_) async => Right(tNumberTrivia));
    // act
    final result = await usecases.execute(number: tNumber);
    //assert
    expect(result, Right(tNumberTrivia));
    verify(mockNumberTriviaRepository.getConcreteNumberTrivia(tNumber));
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockNumberTriviaRepository);
  });
}
```

class NumberTriviaRepository:

```
abstract class NumberTriviaRepository {
  Future<Either<Failure, NumberTrivia>>? getConcreteNumberTrivia(int number);
  Future<Either<Failure, NumberTrivia>>? getRandomNumberTrivia();
}
```

class GetConcreteNumberTrivia:

```
class GetConcreteNumberTrivia {
  final NumberTriviaRepository repo;
  GetConcreteNumberTrivia({
    required this.repo,
  });

  Future<Either<Failure, NumberTrivia>?> execute({required int number}) async {
    return await repo.getConcreteNumberTrivia(number);
  }
}
```